# How can I capture "Align To" into an action?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

Is there any way to capture "**Align To: Selection**" or "**Align To: Canvas**" into an action?

[image]

Comment: I just tried recording "Align to" while testing both align to selection and to canvas, and it seems to record as expected. Are you unable to record these as an action?

Comment: Yes!!! How you did that?

Comment: I didn't do anything special . . . it just worked.

Comment: Do you mean that you managed to record the switching between Selection and Canvas??? If yes, can I have a print screen of your action so to check what it shows?

Comment: Yes, I managed to record them.  It doesn't show as anything different in the action panel however. There is nothing to indicate that you chose "selection" or "canvas", but the choice is respected and recorded. And playback works as expected.

Comment: Strange thing... Doesn't work for me!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131090/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-simonetos-the-greek).